# Amazon SES: Says it's sent test emails but they're not arriving

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, smtp, starttls

I'm trying to switch our Rails app over to using Amazon's SES service for emailing.  The app uses Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.2.2.

SES requires emails to use TLS (ssl-style encryption), which isn't supported in Ruby 1.8.6, but I've found a gem to patch this, here:  https://github.com/seattlerb/smtp_tls

I'm testing sending an email from my console, like so:

```
options = {
    :address => "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    :port => 587,
    :user_name => "my-ses-smtp-username",
    :password => "my-ses-smtp-password",
    :authentication => :login   
  }


smtp = Net::SMTP.new options[:address], options[:port]
smtp.enable_starttls
smtp.start Socket.gethostname, options[:user_name], options[:password], options[:authentication] do |server|
  server.send_message "subject: hello\nblah blah\n\n", "verified_email1@ourdomain.com", "verified_email2@ourdomain.com"
end
```

"verified_email1@ourdomain.com" and "verified_email2@ourdomain.com" have both been verified on SES, and "ourdomain.com" is our registered domain there.

I'm in Sandbox mode on SES and have sent out some emails to the verified addresses using their own email test console, which arrived ok.

The stats page on SES lists one sent email, although the timeline graphs underneath actually say that there have been 6 deliveries and one bounce.  Either way I'd expect to see something come through, but nothing has.

I've put some logging into Net::SMTP to see what's happening with the above request, and it does look OK, from my limited knowledge:

```
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-2007935501 vtiBU5pQUlPZ3bAZIaZl\n", allow_continue = false
net/smtp.rb:648:in `getok': fmt = "EHLO %s"; args = ["max-thinkpad-linux"]
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com\n250-8BITMIME\n250-SIZE 10485760\n250-STARTTLS\n250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\n250 Ok\n", allow_continue = false
net/smtp.rb:648:in `getok': fmt = "STARTTLS"; args = []
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "220 Ready to start TLS\n", allow_continue = false
net/smtp.rb:648:in `getok': fmt = "EHLO %s"; args = ["max-thinkpad-linux"]
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com\n250-8BITMIME\n250-SIZE 10485760\n250-STARTTLS\n250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\n250 Ok\n", allow_continue = false
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6\n", allow_continue = true
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6\n", allow_continue = true
net/smtp.rb:648:in `getok': fmt = "MAIL FROM:<%s>"; args = ["verified_email1@ourdomain.com"]
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "250 Ok\n", allow_continue = false
net/smtp.rb:648:in `getok': fmt = "RCPT TO:<%s>"; args = ["verified_email2@ourdomain.com"]
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "250 Ok\n", allow_continue = false
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\n", allow_continue = true
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "250 Ok 0102015bd896c863-02370584-903e-4c64-b5a0-5c5c5dcc28c6-000000\n", allow_continue = false
net/smtp.rb:648:in `getok': fmt = "QUIT"; args = []
net/smtp.rb:672:in `check_response': res = "221 Bye\n", allow_continue = false
```

Comment: Did you successfully authenticate? I don't see a cleaned up auth section in the output. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication

Comment: The auth works - if I change the password I get an auth failed message.   Maybe because the authentication option is set to "login" it looks different to what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the format of my "Message" part.

It seems that even though I'm passing the from and to address to the `send_message` method, they need to go into the message as standard email headers as well:  setting it up like the following made it work:

```
from = "verified_email1@ourdomain.com"
to = "verified_email2@ourdomain.com"

message = <<HEREDOC
Subject: hello
From: #{from}
To: #{to}

Blah Blah Blah
HEREDOC

smtp = Net::SMTP.new options[:address], options[:port]
smtp.enable_starttls
smtp.start Socket.gethostname, options[:user_name], options[:password], options[:authentication] do |server|
  server.send_message message, from, to
end
```

Ultimately, this will be used by ActionMailer, which will do all this stuff for me.  But, it was the testing-it-in-the-console first step which was tripping me up.